# how can I update a global variable from a multiprocessing callback without overriding the value for other jobs?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, global

so I've written an HTML NLP of sorts in python that uses the multiprocessing library to make things go much faster, but the problem I've run into is that I need access to a global that I uses as a counter so that I can reset it every time the file has changed... now the problem is two fold... one I cannot effect this global counter without effecting the count with the other posses which is not what I want to do, and the other problem is that I cannot make this a instance variable, because the number needs to last longer than the instance lasts... so any help would be greatly appreciated. I was thinking I could change the value of the global with a callback, but that would leave me in the same position as before with it over riding the value for the other worker possesses.

my goal is to override the paragraph_count, so that it gets reset to 0 after each file grope is parsed.

here is my multiprocessing code:

```
def worker(word_output_path, html_output_path, source, filename):
    if filename:
        t = HTML(source)
        output = open(html_output_path, 'w')
        word_out = open(word_output_path,'w')
        with output, word_out:
            try:
                output.write(t.tokenized)
                global word_list

                for w in word_list:
                    if w:
                        word_out.write(w+'\n')
                word_list = []


        except IndexError: 
            output.write(s[1])

        except UnboundLocalError:
            output.write(s[1])



class Implement(HTML):

    def __init__(self, input_path, output_path):
        self.input_path = input_path
        self.output_path = output_path


    def ensure_dir(self, directory):
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)
        return directory    


    def prosses_epubs(self):
        extHTML = ['.html', '.xhtml', '.htm', '.xml']
        pool = mp.Pool()

        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.input_path):
            epubs = [os.path.join(root, file) for file in files
                     if file.endswith('.epub')]
            output_file = [self.ensure_dir(self.output_path+"\\"+os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(e))[0]+'_output\\') for e in epubs]

        for count, e in enumerate(epubs):
            epub = epubLoader(e)
            print os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(e))[0]

            for filename, ext, source, file, epub in epub.get_html_from_epub():
                if ext in extHTML:
                    html_output_path = os.path.normpath(output_file[count]+os.path.dirname(file)+'/'+filename+ext)
                    word_output_path = os.path.normpath(output_file[count]+os.path.dirname(file)+'/'+filename+'.txt')

                    self.ensure_dir(os.path.dirname(html_output_path))

                    pool.apply_async(
                        worker,
                        args=(os.path.normpath(word_output_path), os.path.normpath(html_output_path), source, filename), callback = self.update_value)


                # this is where I will output the other files. 
                else:
                    output_path = os.path.normpath(output_file[count]+os.path.dirname(file)+'/'+filename+ext)

                    epub.extract(file, os.path.normpath(output_file[count]))

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    def update_value(self):
        paragraph_count = 0
```

And as a side note I know one of you will tell me global variables are a bad idea.. and I do agree. but in this case I did not see a good alternative, and that would be the main reason for this question.

Comment: You don't have any code that sets `word_list` anywhere, so this is just going to give you a `NameError`. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a variable which is global, but not global, which is effectively what you're asking for. You'd have the same problem without `multiprocessing`.*

So, you need to pass it in some other way. For example, you can make it local in the top-level function used by each task, or find some other object that *does* last as long as the whole task and make it a member of that, or pass it as an argument, or pass a list with one value as an argument (which allows you to mutably change the value by setting `lst[0] = new_value`), or…

---

In your code, you're not actually using `word_list` at all outside the `while` loop in `worker`, so… there is absolutely no reason for it to be global. However, that's presumably not true in your real code. If you show us your real code (or, better, a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates what you're trying to do without all the extraneous stuff), we can explain how to do what you want. Otherwise, all we can do is give vague explanations.

---

* Actually, `multiprocessing` does make a difference here. Your code is relying on the fact that globals are truly global thanks to multiprocessing working on top of `fork` and the interpreter handling that the way you'd like it to. That isn't guaranteed to work—on Windows, each process will get a separate copy (which means all tasks run by the same process in the pool will share a copy with each other, but not with tasks run by other processes in the pool), and on some uncommon POSIX platforms you'll just segfault.

Comment: makes sense. I think that passing it in as an argument would not be the worst way of doing things. and the reason I am not showing all my code, is because its over 1000 lines so it would be far too much to put in one question. but I really appreciate your help. and I think a perimeter would work.

Comment: @AlexW.H.B.: That's why you need to create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), instead of just posting random fragments of your code that may or may not have the relevant information people need to answer your question.

Comment: @abarnet I will keep that in mind next time. I appreciate you help though.